# jstree massload in different ways

Tags: lazy-loading, jstree

I am using jstree lazy load to display large tree. I want to do

1. **lazy search:**

- I want to search the database for all nodes matching the search string and display them in tree
- I have done this by configuring a search API to return an array of ids of all the nodes which have to be opened to display the nodes matching the search
- The search calls the massload internally, which then provides the data for each node id in a format as
  {
  "id1" : [{ "text" : "Child of ID1", "id" : "c1" }, { "text" : "Another child of ID1", "id" : "c2" }],
  "id2" : [{ "text" : "Child of ID2", "id" : "c3" }]
  }
- Lazy search works fine.

2. **massload descendants on open_node:**

- Now, on expanding any node at level 5, I want to expand all its descendants.
- Should I achieve this through massload? If so, can I make massload behave differently if called through search or if called through load_node?